# Creating motor sound via FFT?

Tags: audio

There is a idle tone of a car. I want to make accelerating and deccelerating that sound by changing ffts.
How can achieve this. I only know C and little bit C++.

Comment: show the code you have crafted so far ... there are tons of fft examples searchable

Comment: I did a program waw2c that converts wav files to the c array file. This song consists of sound of a car from idling to last speed value. Acceleration was properly. I embedded this file into MCU and i streamed via I2S depending speed values. But this approaches is not true. Transitions was sharp. To find a proper car sound that fits my sistem is not easy. Because of that I have to change my approaches. On internet, there are lots of examples(sounds for games) and all of them use FFT method. But I don't know how to do generate engine sound according to three type of sound (idle, acc, decc).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

start with your idle sound array of raw audio [array1] ( this is the payload of a WAV file in PCM format of the car idling ) which will be in the time domain

feed this array1 into a FFT call which will return a new array [array2] which will be the frequency domain representation of the same underlying data as array1 ... where in this new array array2, element zero represents zero Hertz and the freq increment (incr_freq), separating each element, is defined by source sound array1 parms as per

```
incr_freq := sample_rate / number_of_samples_in_array1
```

... value of each element of array2 will be a complex number from which you can calc the magnitude and phase of the given freq ... to be clear frequency with regard to array2 is derived based on element position starting with element zero which is the DC bias and can be ignored ... knowing the frequency increment above (incr_freq) lets show the first few elements of array2

```
complex_number_0  := array2[0]  // element 0 DC bias ignore this element
                                // its frequency_0 = 0

complex_number_1  := array2[1]  // element 1
                                // its at frequency1 =  frequency_0 + incr_freq

complex_number_2  := array2[2]  // element 2
                                // its at frequency2 =  frequency_1 + incr_freq
```

now identify the top X magnitudes in array2 (nugget1) ... these are the dominant frequencies which are most responsible to capture the essence of the car sound ... we save for later the element value of array2 for the X elements ... we calc magnitude using below which is inside loop across all elements of array2

```
for index_fft, curr_complex := range complex_fft { 

    curr_real = real(curr_complex) // pluck out real portion of imaginary number

    curr_imag = imag(curr_complex) // ditto for imaginary part of complex number

    curr_mag = 2.0 * math.Sqrt(curr_real*curr_real+curr_imag*curr_imag) / number_of_samples_array2

    // ... more goodness here
}
```

now feed the array2 FFT array into an inverse FFT call which will return an array [array3] once again in the time domain ( raw audio )

if you do not alter the data of array2 your array3 will be the same (to a first approximation) as array1 ...  now jack up your array2 to impart the acc or dec before sending it into that inverse FFT call

the secret sauce of how to alter array2 is left as an exercise ...  my guess is put into a loop your synthesis of array3 from array2 which gets immediately rendered to your speakers inside this loop (loop_secret_sauce) ... where you increment (acc) or decrement(dec) the top X frequencies as identified above as nugget1 ...  meaning as a whole shift the entire set of freq of all of the top X frequencies as defined by their magnitude ...  give a non linear aspect to this shift of the set of X frequencies ... possibly not only increment or dec the freq of this set but also muck about with their relative magnitudes as well as introduce a wider swatch of frequencies in this loop

to give yourself traction in making this secret sauce use as array1 several different recordings of the car when its at idle or acc or dec and compare its array2 and use the diff between idle, acc, dec inside this sauce loop

here we drill down on mechanics ... when source audio is idle we iterate across its array2 and identify the top X elements of array2 with the greatest magnitude ... these X elements of array2 get saved into array top_mag_idle ... do same for source audio of acc and save in array top_mag_acc ... critical step ...  examine difference between the elements stored in top_mag_idle versus top_mag_acc ... this transition between elements of top_mag_idle into top_mag_acc is your secret sauce which you will put into loop_secret_sauce ... to get concrete here when you loop across loop_secret_sauce and update array2 elements to reflect top_mag_idle the audio will sound idle over time when you continue looping across array2 to synthesize array3 and transition to updating array2 elements to reflect top_mag_acc the sound will be of an accelerating car

perhaps to gain intuition on the secret sauce consider this ... imagine listening to a car on idle ... as with any complex system which generates audio it will have a set of dominant frequencies meaning there are a set of say 5 different frequencies with the greatest magnitude ( loudest freqs )  ... similar to a pianist playing a cord on a piano where the shape of her hand and fingers remain static yet she is repeatedly tapping the keyboard ... now the car starts to accelerate ... the analogy here is she continues to repeatedly tap the keyboard with that same static hand and finger layout yet now she slides her hand up to the right along the keyboard as she continues to tap the keyboard ...  in your code inside loop_secret_sauce the original set of freqs (top_mag_idle) will generate the idle car sound when you synthesize array3 from array2 ... then to implement acc you increment in unison all freqs in top_mag_idle and repeat synthesis of array3 from array2 this will give you the acc sound

until you get this working I would only use mono ( one channel not stereo )

sounds like an interesting project ... have fun !!!

Comment: Trying to understand secret sauce :) I already had an idea till there, but don't know how to do frequency shifting and magnitude manipulation as accelerating and deccelerating after got dominant frequencies of those sound samples. @ScottStensland